# How to get simple array data from firebase and fetch it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im still newbie so i learn firebase instead...

i make simple code for html like this

```
 <div class="container" id="msgs">  
                     </div>
```

so i want to load the data from firebase when document start

```
firebase.database().ref('message').on('value',function(snapshot){
         msgs.innerHTML='';
       
        snapshot.forEach(function(e){
             var data=e.val();
             msgs.innerHTML+='<p>'+$(data.user)+':'+$(data.txt)+'</p>';
        });
       
});
```

but its returns:

[image]

my data is like this:

[image]

i just want to learn simple way how to retrieve the data and fetch it to html and learn how to access firebase array... thanksss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
msgs.innerHTML+='<p>'+$(data.user)+':'+$(data.txt)+'</p>';
```

The `$(data.user)` and `$(data.txt)` are trying t look up the value of HTML nodes. That's not what you want, as you simply want to use the value of the `data.user` and `data.txt` properties.

So:

```
msgs.innerHTML+='<p>'+data.user+':'+data.txt+'</p>';
```

Comment: Btw.. User is return as database name or variable that i declare for send data?